# prevent url encoding after git clone

Tags: git, tfs

I have a repository in TFS, which has a space in a folder name:

```
/Bla/Di Bla/
```

when I use:

```
git clone https...
```

It URI encodes it like so:

```
/Bla/Di%20Bla/
```

is there anything I can do to prevent this (and no the folder naming is out of my control)? Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean "is encodes"? when you want to do `git clone` you must to put in the URL `%20`?

Comment: Yes this is the uri encoded adress: http://xyz:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_git/Bla/Di%20Bla/  but the physical folder name should be: /Bla/Di Bla/ I do not want git to use uri encoded names for the folder after cloning!

Comment: in the `git clone` you can determine the folder name, do you know how?

Comment: sorry i do not understand

Comment: please see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this command:

`git clone xyz:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_git/Bla/Di%20Bla "C:/Path/To/Folder/Di Bla"`

Now the git repo will be in folder `Di Bla` and not in `Di%20Bla`.

Comment: Thanks - that helped!